# Lenovo tab 7 does not see apk in Store

Tags: java, android

This device does not see apk in store , a samsumg tab a see application in google store . This is my andorid Mainifest :

I use this perrmissions :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I can instal on lenovo device this application on file apk and is working but when I try find this application in store I can not see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add support for multiple screens.
Use below given code in **AndroidManifest.xml** below the permissions and outside the **application** tag

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: Ok I will try do it :)

Comment: @Kala You can also this by generating signed apk and then try to install it on your device

Comment: I intall this apk by generating signed apk and then try to install it on your device  and is working but I want to deplay this apk to play store

Comment: and i added this tags but I steal do not see this application and also I see error : DF_DFERH-01

Comment: if it is working now, then it will surely work from playstore as well. Otherwise it would have shown some kind of error like "Application not compatible".

Comment: please wait to let the latest version app available on PlayStore. It usually takes half an hour.

Comment: Now I see that a Application not compatible

Comment: When I do this a device see apllication  :     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

Comment: maybe your device does not support camera permissions

Comment: Ok but Thanks for help :)